# ¡Feliz cumpleaños Stack Overflow en español!

Tags: discusión

Hace un año se iniciaba el beta privado de Stack Overflow en español.

[image: Area 51 mostrando 365 días]

Y recibíamos el mail con la invitación.

[image: mail de Area51 invitando al beta privado]

¡Es momento de brindar por ello!

Gracias a todos los que contribuyen día a día para mejorar el sitio y aportar contenido de calidad. Como parte de la comunidad, creo que ha sido un año espectacular, con grandes avances y hemos observado el continuo crecimiento del sitio.

Aprovechemos la ocasión para celebrar, comentando qué es lo que más nos gusta de la comunidad, cuáles son los deseos para el próximo año del sitio, qué anécdotas memorables ocurrieron durante este año, o qué publicaciones les traen buenos recuerdos.

A todos, ¡muy feliz año!

Comment: ¡Felicidades a todos!

Comment: ¡¡Felicidades!!

Comment: Salú! Felicidades

Comment: eeeeeeeeepaaaa!!! Saludos a toda la hermandad :D

Comment: Coincidentemente hoy es mi cumpleaños también =P

Comment: Javi verde tuyu, javi verde tuyu...

Comment: ¡¡Muchísimas felicidades a todos!! La verdad que poco puedo decir sobre que anécdotas han pasado durante este año ya que llevo muy poco tiempo en el sitio. Sin embargo, puedo decir lo que me ha gustado (y ha hecho quedarme): he visto muy buen ambiente aquí, que está en español y no hay casi nada de documentación en español por Internet (ya es hora de que esto empiece a cambiar) y preguntas y respuestas buenas y de calidad. Estoy aprendiendo mucho a la vez que intento enseñar con lo que sé. Para el año nuevo: Más y mejor. ¡¡Y con una comunidad mucho más grande!!

Comment: ¡Felicidades! :)

Comment: Excelente, espero pronto el sitio deje de ser beta!

Comment: Hemos pasado un gran año y esperamos tener más en el futuro. ¡Felicidades a todos!

Comment: Primero de muchos muchach@s!!!!!

Comment: Feliz cumpleaños a todos!!!

Comment: y que sean muchos mas! Al gran SO latino salud!

Comment: ¡Felicidades a todos!

Comment: Felicidades a todos! Me gusta ayudar y aprender, espero colaborar mucho. Saludos.

Comment: Felicidades! Aprovecho este año para preguntar cuándo llegarla a SOes la parte de la documentación que han estrenado este año SOen. Y bueno felices fiestas a todos ya de paso :)

Comment: Felicidades a todos y muchas gracias por ayudar :)